# JMX bean in an application that has multiple webapps deployed to JBoss 5.0.1 GA

Tags: spring, jboss, jmx

I am trying to configure JMX management for a bean of mine used by 2 webapps in one JavaEE app. The application is deployed to JBoss 5.0.1 GA. Here is my JMX config

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="bean:name=myJMXBean"
                   value-ref="myService"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="assembler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.InterfaceBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
            <property name="managedInterfaces">
                <value>
                    com.me.MyServiceJMXInterface
                </value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="server" ref="mBeanServer"/>      
</bean>
```

At the beginning, I got error like MBean bean:name=myJMXBean already registered. Figured it must be the MBean getting registered in the 2 webapps in my app. THen I added the following line to the bean exporter

The error is gone. But if I try to use JConsole to access the MBean and change the value, it is kind of unknown which instance of myService that I'm getting. It must be a well-defined problem seen by many people before. Can someone please shed some light onto how I can do this?

Hope I make it clear. Thanks a lot for your kind helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 things that might help you.

1. The name of the MBean that you are registering must be unique.
2. When your app shuts down or restart you must **unregister the MBean**. I was getting a lot of these "already registered bean" and the problem was that I never unregistered it with a callback method in my app when it was shutting down.